# Iteratively declaring distinct variables

Tags: unique, z3, distinct-values

This question is strongly related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14955455/distinct-values-in-z3/14956253#14956253) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406557/z3-unique-assignment) question.

The `distinct` function of Z3

```
(declare-const a S)
(declare-const b S)
(assert (distinct a b))
```

allows constraining sets of variables (here `a` and `b`) such that all variables in the set must take different values.

**My question is**: is it also possible to force a variable to take a unique value without explicitly referring to the set of variables from which it should be distinct? Something like

```
(declare-unique-const a S)
(declare-unique-const b S)
(declare-unique-const c S)
```

This would be nice in situations where you declare new variables in an iterative process, for example, during program verification.

If it is not possible, I guess one has to keep track of all distinct variables and use that set to emit appropriate `distinct (newvar, oldvar1, ..., oldvarn))` constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can define an auxiliary fresh function `f` from `S` to `Int`, and assert

```
f(a_1) = 1
f(a_1) = 2
f(a_3) = 3
...
f(a_n) = n
```

Then, `a_1`, ..., `a_n` must be different from each other.
If we want to say that `b` is also different from all `a_i`s. We just assert

```
f(b) = n+1
```

In this approach, we only have to track the counter.

Comment: Any idea which of the two approaches might perform better? Tracking all variables and `distinct` vs tracking a counter and functions?

Comment: For small sets of variables `distinct` is usually better. Remark: if the number of arguments in `distinct(a_1, ..., a_n)` is big, then Z3 will use the trick above to encode the `distinct`. It does that to avoid the quadratic blowup.